# Where does jQuery data's method information go?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I do

```
<div class="some_div">some div</div>
<script>
    jQuery('.some_div').data('some_data','some info').remove();
</script>
```

where the information is added with data's method, is still around the DOM? Do I need to uninitialize? Is the information automatically removed when the div element has no references left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is stored in a variable available to the jQuery objects via closure. **It is never stored in the dom.** Remove method deletes the data along with the DOM element.

> **.remove( [ selector ] )**
>
> Similar to .empty(), the .remove()
>    method takes elements out of the DOM. 
>   We use .remove() when we want to
>   remove the element itself, as well as 
>   everything inside it. **In addition to
>   the elements themselves, all bound 
>   events and jQuery data associated with
>   the elements are removed**.

source: jQuery API: [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery places a serial number on DOM elements when needed, and uses that reference to look up associated data for the element.

For example: `jQuery1278101043588: 1`

As long as the element exists, your data should exist. No references to the element in code are needed.

The data associated with an element is cleaned up when you call `.remove()` or `.empty()`.

If you wish to remove an element from the DOM without losing the data, you can use `.detach()`.

- http://api.jquery.com/remove/
- http://api.jquery.com/empty/
- http://api.jquery.com/detach/

jQuery also has a `.removeData()` method for clearing data that is no longer needed. It will clear all data on the element(s) if called without passing an argument.

- http://api.jquery.com/removeData/

Comment: +1 for going into the details. Also, the data can be inspected using the value associated with jQuery's unique id. In your example it's `1`, so the storage area will be at `jQuery.cache[1]`. That works for now :)